# is it possible to delete the object after it returned?

Tags: python, memory, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, contextmanager

I want to delete some object after it returned function 
for example

```
def  A():
    imgA = img_generator()
    return imgA

def  B():
     for i in range(1000000):
          imgB = A()
```

if I want to delete the memory usage of A()'s imgA. how should I do it?

Comment: What is the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: Python's garbage collection is pretty smart so normally you don't have to worry about these kind of things

Comment: When exactly do you think that you want `imgA` to be deleted? When do you think that it is being deleted in the code you posted?

Comment: first: you can use `return img_generator()` and you don't have this variable. Second: Python doesn't duplicate object when you send it from function but it send rather reference - so if you really delete object in `imgA` then you also delete object in `imgB`. So there is no need to delete `imgA`

Answer (score 0):

The reference of `imgA` is been overwritten each time in the for loop, so only one instance of `imgA` is in memory at the same time. For deleting memory usage of variables you can do 2 things: use `del imgA` or assing it to `None` like this `imgA = None`. The difference is that in the first case, the variable is completely removed from the `namespace` and sent to the `Garbage Collector` and the second case, the variable is still alive but its content is sent to the `Garbage Collector`. However in `python` you shouldn't worry about those things since it's handled automatically for you.